# jQuery ScrollTop..."disable" when hit bottom of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to implement a parallax scroll (got two separate elements) #slides and #body, the #body will overlay the #slides when you scroll down the page (parallax effect)

Problem arises when you scroll right to the bottom of the page, it appears to jump...think it is looking at the height.

here is the code.

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function () {
var n1 = ($(this).scrollTop() / 0.2)+'px';
  $('#slides').css({ 'top': 0-($(this).scrollTop() / 0.9) + "px"});
 console.log(n1);
  $('#body').css({ 'margin-top': 0-($(this).scrollTop() / 0.45) + "px"});   
});


$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100)         {
    alert("bottom!");
}
});

</script>
```

I am wanting to create a jquery function to "disable" this slide when it hits the **footer** HTML tag? any ideas how to write this. I have done an "alert" so this fires when you scroll down...but wanting to transfer this into "disbaling" jQuery scroll

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this now, this can be removed